# No invoice option on account menu

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

Hope I am in the ibm-bluemix group. Any idea how to get an invoice on pay as you go accounts ? The credit card charges do not match up to usage summaries. Getting ready to dump bluemix as it seems to have degraded over these past 6-18 months.

Comment: This seems like a support and not programming question. You should contact the IBM support.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a programming question, here are the answers to your questions. There is an updated FAQ available to answer these questions. See:
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/04/bluemix-id-and-billing-faq/

In it, here is the information about the invoice:

**Q: How do I get information about my invoice?**

There are different ways to obtain your invoice depending on your type of account.

If you have a Bluemix account linked to a Bluemix Infrastructure account, you can view your invoice within the Bluemix Administrative Console using these steps:

1. Log in to [Bluemix](http://console.bluemix.net/).
2. Click **Manage** and select **Billing and Usage > Invoices**.
3. Click an invoice

**Note**: You must have a Bluemix and Bluemix Infrastructure (formerly SoftLayer) linked account to see the Invoices option. For more information, see [Linking your Bluemix and SoftLayer accounts](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/pricing/linking_accounts.html#unifyingaccounts).

If you have a Bluemix subscription or a Pay-Per-Use account, you can request an invoice through the [Invoices On-Line](https://iolus.iolportal.com/IBMIOLUS/EBPP/Company/IBMIOL) site. Use the same IBM ID and password that you use to log into Bluemix. If you cannot log in, go to the **Register Here** option and select the appropriate choice for obtaining invoices for your account. For more information about invoices, access the [IBM Customer Support web site](http://www.ibm.com/support/operations/zz/en/selectcountrylang.html), select your region, and click **Frequently Asked Questions > Invoices and payments**.

---

In terms of the usage information versus billing, this information might help you:

**Q. What is the difference between what is shown on the Usage Dashboard and what is billed?**

Look at Account dashboard to see the free allotments for the services that you are using. Free allotments are applied to the account level and not the organization level. In addition, the differences depend on your type of account as explained below:

- Subscription: The billed contractual interval is based upon a negotiated payment for usage credits. The bill does not necessarily equal your usage.
- Trial: The Account Dashboard lists the estimated cost of your environment if you had a pay-per-use account.
- Pay-Per-Use: The Usage Dashboard lists what you owe including free allotments that are provided by some services. Note: Some third-party services, such as SendGrid, do not bill for their service through Bluemix if you signed up for their service outside of Bluemix.

If you have separate Platform as a Service (Paas) and Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS – formerly known as SoftLayer ) accounts, you will be billed separately. However, you can get one combined bill if you link your accounts. For more information, see [Linking your Bluemix and SoftLayer accounts](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/pricing/linking_accounts.html#unifyingaccounts).

If you have further questions about your bill, please submit a Support ticket.